# Get javascript calulations to post as form data and display in php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am somewhat familiar with JavaScript and php and very familiar with HTML but have limited experience in getting them to work together. I have looked at many examples and am either not understanding or other posts do not specifically address my situation. I am trying to accomplish two things at the time of form  submission. One is to retrieve the information from a div populated by innerHTML to post with the form and the other is to generate a unique number for the transaction at form posting and then display.
I have an HTML form that displays a generated list, each of which has a check box beside it. When a check box is selected I am using onclick="calTotal()" to calculate and display the total of all boxes checked. Code listed below.
The display script works perfectly and displays a value such as Total $125.00. What I need to do is post that total value when I post the form. The only value being passed at this time is the last check box value. Should that total be assigned within the JavaScript or should it be assigned within an input field? 
The second part of my question is with the value of my algorithm that creates a unique transaction number. I want to generate that number upon submission of the form but then need to have it display on the php page. I have tested my algorithm separately and know it works correctly when I hard code the values in. I need to take values from the form and use them to calculate the transaction number. Once calculated it needs to be passed to the php page. Again I am not completely sure where to assign the value so that it passes to the next page. 
Anything that will get me pointed in the right direction is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calTotal() {
    var ch, i=0;
    var total=0;
    while(ch=document.getElementsByName("amt")[i++]) {
      if (ch.checked) 
      {
        total=total+Number(ch.value);
      }
    }
    var div=document.getElementById('divTotal');
    total="$"+total.toFixed(2);
    div.innerHTML= "Total: " +total;
    return total;
  }

function calTrans(x,y,z)
  {
  do calculations here

  // concatenate into Trans number
  var transNum=rm.concat(em,tm,am);
  return transNum;
  }
</script>

<form id="frmcheckout" action="out.php" method="post" onsubmit=calTrans()>
<table cellspacing="25">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Selection</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="amt" value="$cost" onclick="calTotal()"></td>
    <td>$Title</td>
    <td>$cost</td>
  </tr>
#end
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        E-mail address:<input type="text" name="email" value="E-mail required">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="divTotal"></div>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit";>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using hidden fields? e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="" >
```

You can use the same method for your unique transaction id. Then you can populate the hidden fields when you populate your "divTotal" div. e.g

```
document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```

This way when the form is submitted, the value will be passed to the script as "total" (in my example above). You can get values in php like this:

```
<?php
$total = $_POST["total"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$transactionId = generateTransId(<<someparams>>);//YOUR FUNCTION TO CREATE TRANS ID
?>
```

Then to display your transaction id or output it anywhere on your php page, this is one example:

```
<div id="transId"><?php echo $transactionId; ?></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help understanding this. Using your solution I was able to get the total to post correctly. With understanding how to get the values from the form fields I was also able to get the information passed to my script for the transaction id and that id is now included in the post variables.